# How can I get Visual Studio 2017 to sign a Win32 application automatically?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, code-signing

I am using visual studio 2017. I am not a developer. I am just trying to write a simple parsing script and I am familiar with visual studio. I use Atmel Studio(which is based off VS) to write embedded code, but I don't have to deal with signing. I installed visual studio on my work computer and now I get bit9 errors every time I make a new build.

Internal IT has pointed me to a bunch of slightly outdated certificate stuff. I now have a certificate to apply to my builds, however the process defined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-sign-application-and-deployment-manifests) will apparently not work for a Win32 application. I do not have a Signing tab in the project properties.

I have also looked into the visual studio command line using signtool. However, it would take a lot of my time to learn how it works and implement it.

Hopefully someone else has solved this and I can save the time. If there are no easy solutions I'll just go back to manually parsing, because this has already taken up to much of my time.

Comment: Did IT give you a pfx ? (and the password, of course). Just curious. I had to do this with VS2010 and VS2015. Unless MS finally integrated it into the IDE for project configuration in VS 2017 for unmanaged C++ (and it sounds like it still isn't), you can indeed use signtool, and it isn't that difficult so long as you have the pfx and associated password.

Comment: @WhozCraig They gave me a link to a microsoft site to generate my own pfx. So yes. I have a pfx with a password I set up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how i've done this with Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2015 for unmanaged C or C++ Win32 applications. You need:

- A signing certificate. This is normally given as a PFX when working in Windows, and is typically an intermediate certificate in your certificate chain.
- The password to the above PFX to decrypt the certificate private key.

With those, the following custom build step for your Win32 project can be created:

```
"$(FrameworkSDKDir)bin\x86\signtool.exe" sign /v /f "path-to-your-cert\yourcert.pfx" /p password "$(TargetPath)" > "$(OutDir)sign\$(ProjectName)-sign.out"
```

This will use your certificate to sign the project output (be it a DLL or EXE makes no difference), and record the output of the signing certificate in a file named after your project with the suffix `sign.out`, placing that file in a folder called `sign` off your output directory.

That may seem a bit overkill, but there is a reason for that generated output file. By creating that file, and naming it as one of the "Outputs" of the custom build step:

[image]

it can be comparatively used to determine whether to re-sign or not. Each time the project is built, if the target image (your exe or dll) is regenerated that output file will be out-of-date and the custom build step will be kicked off to regenerate it (and thusly also re-sign the image). The sign.out file, btw, will contain something like this:

```
The following certificate was selected:
    Issued to: The Signing Cert Name Here

    Issued by: The Issuer Cert Name Here

    Expires:   Sat Dec 31 16:59:59 2039

    SHA1 hash: 232C80E19EBC71330E7C12CA8C07B345B1531777


Done Adding Additional Store
Successfully signed: full-path-to-image-here

Number of files successfully Signed: 1

Number of warnings: 0

Number of errors: 0
```

Once you have your PFX and password, you can easily just hand-test the command before you finally configure it as part of the build. The only real wildcard I've seen is the full path to the signtool.exe, which seemingly changes from time to time (different with VS2008 than with VS2015, for example.

Anyway, that's how I did it. Hopefully you can too.

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping I could do with the command line!

Forgive my ignorance, but I want to make sure I get this right. 

I will be replacing "path-to-your-cert\yourcert.pfx" with the full path to my cert. 

I will replace "$(TargetPath)" with my password as plaintext?

Comment: @NateSan You can totally do it from the command line as well (obviously). You must have `signtool.exe` in your path, which it would be automatically if you are running from a Visual Studio Command Prompt. I thought (perhaps mistakenly) you were looking to incorporate it directly into your solution and project files. If so, the above is applicable. If not, and you only wanted a command line, only a fraction of the above will really be required (the actual command).

Comment: Ignore the previous question. The edit system is messing with me. 

So "$(FrameworkSDKDir)bin\\x86\signtool.exe" may or may not be accurate for my version.

sign /v /f "path-to-your-cert\yourcert.pfx" just gets replaced by the full directory to the pxf?

/p password becomes /p whateverthepassis  with no quotes.

"$(TargetPath)" is the path to the folder containing the exe?

"$(OutDir) could be the same as the above directory, right?

sign\$(ProjectName)-sign.out" project name becomes whatever the project is called spaces and all?

Comment: @NateSan Yup, that's pretty much it. signtool does the rest. Usually this is done as part of a company's official build system, as they're the only ones that have the company signing cert (usually issued by Verisign, Thawt, or some other trusted authority) under lock and key, and are the only ones that can spit out "official" company-signed bits. But if you also need authenticode signing as part of your internal security checks, etc, this is one way to do it, usually using a development-generated/managed certificate chain. Anyway, hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you, but I'm getting an error, but I don't see the issue. compile fails and returns 1, which i assume is fail. The sign.out shows nothing when opened with notepad++.


"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.15063.0\x86\signtool.exe" sign /v /f "C:\Users\nate_roth\Documents\Certifications\cert.pfx" /p mypassword "$(C:\Users\nate_roth\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\CySmart Log Parser\Debug)" > "$(C:\Users\nate_roth\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\CySmart Log Parser\Debug)sign\$(Cysmart Log Parser)-sign.out"

Comment: Your macro usage for your to-be-signed is wrong. Note the $ at the beginning, which shouldn't be there. And the value is wrong anyway, as it's a full path with no file name (no DLL or EXE; just the Debug output folder). Fix that macro and it should fix your problem, assuming your certificate and its password are correct.

Comment: that fixed the error, but I'm still getting bit9 flags from my company's security. So I'll just have to get back with them. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @NateSan that is most likely because either client auth isn't configured correctly or the server public cert they undoubtedly had you self-sign is not in their trusted store. Ideally whatever signing cert signed your executable is rooted issued by an authority your company's security ultimately trusts. Frankly, them sending you to gen a self-signed cert for this seems a little ludicrous. Anyway, best of luck.

Comment: This was exactly the issue. I had to get in touch with a higher level IT guy. It works now. I do have a small annoyance though. I have to manually rebuild every time for the cert to be applied. Letting it build when i ask it to debug or run without debug still throws errors. Is there anything I can do do apply the cert on every build?

Comment: The signature should only requiring being done when the module (be it an exe or a dll) is built. That is the reason for the custom build step, and the detection of the sign-out file being out-of-date with the exe/dll should trigger an automatic resign. if it doesn't then chances are your macros aren't configured precisely as I described (but close). Make sure they correct.